# Display or Hide a list element based on another variable value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to Angular/Ionic. I have a ionic list created as follows. I want to Display/Hide an item in list depends on a value in item.display varaible. My code is shown as below

```
<ion-list id="item-list7" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" >

//below item should display or hide with respect to value in item.display
<ion-item  id="item{{item.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left assertive" >
{{item.item_name}}
</ion-item>

<ion-list>
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: you can use ng-if or ng-show and ng-hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide), like this:

**ng-show**

```
 <ion-item ng-show="item.display" id="item{{item.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left assertive" >
```

**ng-hide**

```
 <ion-item ng-hide="!item.display" id="item{{item.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left assertive" >
```

.

You can also use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to hide an element but beware: it will also remove it from the DOM.

**ng-if**

```
<ion-item ng-if="item.display" id="item{{item.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left assertive" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How should I check ng-show="item.display=anotherVariable" ?

Comment: In the way you wrote it: ng-show="item.display == anotherVariable". Obiviously, anotherVariable needs to be defined in a scope (see $scope, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the help